# How can I set a page break dynamically depending on size of tables?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am printing many dynamically generated tables whose sizes will vary, and I would like to find a way to set a page break before a table if it will not entirely fit on the page. How could this be done?

Comment: You mean when printing the web-page?

Comment: yes i havea css dedicated to printing already just the tables get split between pages

Comment: Have you tried playing with page-break-before css property?

Comment: yes but the problem is the tables are all different sizes so i would not know which one to put a page break before on

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
table {
    page-break-inside: avoid; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a page-break-before on all tables in combination with `<thead>`.  Then it would start each new table on its own page and any that run over one page would get a repeating header on subsequent pages (i.e. the thead).